# Wordpress Aceder ficheiro do plugin no url

Tags: php, plugin-wordpress

Tenho um plugin no wordpress instalado no seguinte caminho:

```
  site_wordpress/wp-content/plugins/meuplugin
```

Dentro do meu plugin tenho um arquivo `parameter.php` que que eu tenho acesso através do painel da administração do wordpress onde configuro os parametros do do plugin.

Existe um outro arquivo tambem chamado `list.php` que eu quero aceder da seguinte forma:

```
 http://site_wordpress/list
```